# routes in nodejs/express get called twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

im working in an existing project, and i have a problem driving me insane:

the routes are getting called twice or maybe even more, this happens when any route called take too long to respond

i think the problem is in this file, a dynamic routing attempt

```
            var express = require('express');
            var recaptcha = require('express-recaptcha');
            //Site key, Secret key
            recaptcha.init('xxxxx', 'yyyyy');
            /**
             * Routes middleware
             * Check all requests
             */
            module.exports = function(app, passport, memoryCache) {

              var router = express.Router();
              var config = require('app/config/settings.js');

              router.use(function(req, res, next) {

                console.log("touch");
                console.log(req.url);
                /**
                 * Make visible req / res on template layout
                 */
                res.locals.req = req;
                res.locals.res = res;
                /**
                 * Url filter
                 */
                var aryUrl = req.path.split('/').filter(Boolean);

                try {

                  var root = '';
                  var controller = '';
                  var controllerPrototype = '';
                  var module = '';
                  var method = '';
                  var url = '';
                  var itemId = '';
                  var privacity = '';
                  var session = '';

                  switch (req.originalMethod) {
                    case 'GET':
                      method = 'get';
                      break;
                    case 'POST':
                      method = 'post';
                      break;
                    case 'PUT':
                      method = 'put';
                      break;
                    case 'DELETE':
                      method = 'delete';
                      break;
                  }

                  if (aryUrl.length == 0) {
                    root = '/';
                  } else {
                    root = aryUrl[0];
                  }

                  switch (root) {
                    case '/':
                      privacity = 'private';
                      session = 'General';
                      module = 'app/controllers/indexController';
                      controller = 'index';
                      controllerPrototype = 'root';
                      url = '/';

                      break;
                    case 'index':
                      privacity = 'private';
                      session = 'General';
                      module = 'app/controllers/indexController';
                      controller = 'index';
                      controllerPrototype = aryUrl[1];
                      url = '/index/' + aryUrl[1];

                      break;
                    case 'evaluaciones':
                      privacity = 'private';
                      session = 'PortalEval';
                      module = 'app/controllers/view-private/portalEvaluacionController';
                      controller = 'portalEvaluacion';
                      controllerPrototype = 'view';
                      url = '/evaluaciones';

                      if (aryUrl.length == 2) {
                          if (aryUrl[1] === 'antesdelcurso' || aryUrl[1] === 'despuesdelcurso') {
                              url = url + '/' + aryUrl[1];
                          } else {
                              controller = '';
                          }
                      }
                      break;
                    case 'relatores':
                        privacity = 'private';
                        session = 'RelatorEval';
                        module = 'app/controllers/portalRelatoresIndexController';
                        controller = 'portalRelatores';
                        controllerPrototype = 'view';
                        url = '/relatores';
                        break;
                    case 'api-pc':
                      privacity = 'public';
                      session = (req.user)? req.user.tipoSession : '';
                      var ctrl = aryUrl[1].replace(/\W+(.)/g, function(x, chr) {
                        return chr.toUpperCase();
                      });
                      ctrl = 'api' + ctrl.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + ctrl.slice(1);

                      module = 'app/controllers/api-public/' + ctrl + 'Controller';
                      controller = ctrl;

                      if (aryUrl.length == 4) {
                        itemId = '/:id';
                      }

                      controllerPrototype = aryUrl[2];

                      url = '/api-pc/' + aryUrl[1] + '/' + aryUrl[2] + itemId;

                      break;
                    case 'api-pt':
                      privacity = 'private';
                      session = (req.user)? req.user.tipoSession : '';
                      var ctrl = aryUrl[1].replace(/\W+(.)/g, function(x, chr) {
                        return chr.toUpperCase();
                      });
                      ctrl = 'api' + ctrl.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + ctrl.slice(1);

                      module = 'app/controllers/api-private/' + ctrl + 'Controller';
                      controller = ctrl;

                      if (aryUrl.length == 4) {
                        itemId = '/:id';
                      }

                      controllerPrototype = aryUrl[2];

                      url = '/api-pt/' + aryUrl[1] + '/' + aryUrl[2] + itemId;

                      break;
                    case 'view-pc':
                      privacity = 'public';
                      session = (req.user)? req.user.tipoSession : '';
                      var ctrl = aryUrl[1].replace(/\W+(.)/g, function(x, chr) {
                        return chr.toUpperCase();
                      });

                      module = 'app/controllers/view-public/' + ctrl + 'Controller';
                      controller = ctrl;

                      if (aryUrl.length == 4) {
                        itemId = '/:id';
                      }

                      controllerPrototype = aryUrl[2];

                      url = '/view-pc/' + aryUrl[1] + '/' + aryUrl[2] + itemId;

                      break;
                    case 'view-pt':
                      privacity = 'private';
                      session = (req.user)? req.user.tipoSession : '';
                      var ctrl = aryUrl[1].replace(/\W+(.)/g, function(x, chr) {
                        return chr.toUpperCase();
                      });

                      module = 'app/controllers/view-private/' + ctrl + 'Controller';
                      controller = ctrl;

                      if (aryUrl.length == 4) {
                        itemId = '/:id';
                      }

                      controllerPrototype = aryUrl[2];

                      url = '/view-pt/' + aryUrl[1] + '/' + aryUrl[2] + itemId;

                      break;
                    case 'auth':
                      /**
                      * Local Login
                      */
                      var successGetLog = function(req, res) {
                        res.render('login/get.html', {
                          layout: 'layout/auth.html',
                          entorno: config.config_entorno.empresa,
                          message: req.flash('loginMessage'),
                          loginAttempts: req.flash('loginAttempts')
                        });
                      };

                      var successPostLog = function (req, res) {
                        var loginAttempts = res.locals.req.user.loginAttempts;
                        if (loginAttempts >= 4){
                          recaptcha.verify(req, function(error){
                            if(error){ //Falla de verificacion de captcha
                              res.render('login/get.html', {
                                layout: 'layout/auth.html',
                                entorno: config.config_entorno.empresa,
                                message: req.flash('loginMessage'),
                                loginAttempts: loginAttempts,
                                captcha:recaptcha.render()
                              });
                            } else { //Exito de verificacion de captcha
                              res.redirect('/');
                            }
                          });
                        } else {
                          res.redirect('/');
                        }
                      };

                      var successGetLogout = function(req, res) {
                        req.logout();
                        res.redirect('/');
                      };

                      router.route('/auth/login').get(successGetLog);

                      router.route('/auth/login').post(passport.authenticate("local-login", {failureRedirect: '/auth/logout'}), successPostLog);

                      router.route('/auth/logout').get(successGetLogout);

                      /**
                      * Encuesta Local Login
                      */
                      var successGetPortalLog = function(req, res) {
                          if (req.query.rut != undefined || req.query.token == 'bciboost') {
                              if (req.query.rut != undefined && req.query.token == 'bciboost') {
                                  console.log('casi');
                                  req.body = {
                                      rut: req.query.rut,
                                      password: 'null'
                                  };
                                  passport.authenticate('portaleval-link-login', function(err, user, info) {
                                      if (err) {
                                          return next(err);
                                      }
                                      if (!user) {
                                          res.render('portalevaluacionapp/portal_evaluacion_login.html', {
                                              layout: 'layout/empty.html',
                                              entorno: config.config_entorno.empresa,
                                              message: req.flash('loginMessage'),
                                              access: req.path,
                                          });
                                      }
                                      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                                          if (err) {
                                              return next(err);
                                          }
                                          if (user) {
                                              res.redirect('/evaluaciones');
                                          }
                                      });
                                  })(req, res, next);
                              } else {
                                  res.render('portalevaluacionapp/portal_evaluacion_login.html', {
                                      layout: 'layout/empty.html',
                                      entorno: config.config_entorno.empresa,
                                      message: 'Existe un problema al iniciar sesión',
                                      access: req.path,
                                  });
                              }
                          } else {
                              if (Object.keys(req.session.passport).length !== 0 && req.session.passport.constructor === Object && req.path === '/auth/evaluaciones' && req.session.passport.user.type === 'PortalEval') {
                                  res.redirect('/evaluaciones');
                              } else {
                                  res.render('portalevaluacionapp/portal_evaluacion_login.html', {
                                      layout: 'layout/empty.html',
                                      entorno: config.config_entorno.empresa,
                                      message: req.flash('loginMessage'),
                                      access: req.path,
                                  });
                              };
                          }
                      }

                      var successPostPortalLog = function(req, res) {
                        res.redirect(req.path.replace('/auth', ''));
                      };

                      var successGetPortalLogout = function(req, res) {
                          req.logout();
                          res.redirect(req.path.replace('/logout', ''));
                      };

                      var successGetPortalRelatorLogout = function(req, res) {
                          req.logout();
                          res.redirect("/auth/relatores");
                      };

                      if (req.path === '/auth/evaluaciones' || req.path === '/auth/evaluaciones/antesdelcurso' || req.path === '/auth/evaluaciones/despuesdelcurso') {
                        var rutAux = req.body.rut;
                        req.body = {
                            rut: (typeof rutAux === 'undefined' || rutAux === '')? 'null': req.body.rut,
                            password: 'null'
                        };
                      }

                      router.route('/auth/evaluaciones').get(successGetPortalLog);
                      router.route('/auth/evaluaciones/antesdelcurso').get(successGetPortalLog);
                      router.route('/auth/evaluaciones/despuesdelcurso').get(successGetPortalLog);

                      router.route('/auth/evaluaciones').post(passport.authenticate("portaleval-login", {failureRedirect: '/auth/evaluaciones'}), successPostPortalLog);
                      router.route('/auth/evaluaciones/antesdelcurso').post(passport.authenticate("portaleval-login", {failureRedirect: '/auth/evaluaciones'}), successPostPortalLog);
                      router.route('/auth/evaluaciones/despuesdelcurso').post(passport.authenticate("portaleval-login", {failureRedirect: '/auth/evaluaciones'}), successPostPortalLog);

                      router.route('/auth/evaluaciones/logout').get(successGetPortalLogout);
                      router.route('/auth/evaluaciones/logout/antesdelcurso').get(successGetPortalLogout);
                      router.route('/auth/evaluaciones/logout/despuesdelcurso').get(successGetPortalLogout);

                      var successGetRelatorLog = function(req, res) {
                          res.render('portalrelatoresapp/portal_relatores_login.html', {
                              layout: 'layout/empty.html',
                              entorno: config.config_entorno.empresa,
                              message: req.flash('loginMessage'),
                              access: req.path,
                          });
                      };


                      var successPostRelatorPortalLog = function(req, res) {
                        res.redirect(req.path.replace('/auth', ''));
                      };




                      router.route('/auth/relatores').get(successGetRelatorLog);
                      router.route('/auth/relatores').post(passport.authenticate("portalrelatores-login", {failureRedirect: '/auth/relatores'}), successPostPortalLog);
                      router.route('/auth/relatores/logout').get(successGetPortalRelatorLogout);



                      break;
                    default:

                      break;
                  }

                  if (controller != '') {
                    var controllerDynamic = require(module);

                    controllerDynamic.req = req;
                    controllerDynamic.res = res;

                    /**
                     * Auth validation
                     */
                    if (privacity == 'private') {
                      if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
                        if (session == 'General') {
                          if (controllerDynamic.auth.indexOf('PortalEval') != -1) {
                            var err = new Error(402);
                            throw err;
                          }
                        } else
                        if (session == 'PortalEval') {
                            if (controllerDynamic.auth.indexOf('General') != -1) {
                                var err = new Error(401);
                                throw err;
                            }
                        } else
                        if (session == 'RelatorEval') {
                            if (controllerDynamic.auth.indexOf('General') != -1) {
                                var err = new Error(401);
                                throw err;
                            }
                        }
            //==============================================================================
                         else
                        if (session == 'PortalRelator') {
                          if (controllerDynamic.auth.indexOf('PortalRelator') == -1) {
                            var err = new Error(402);
                            throw err;
                          }
                        }
            //==============================================================================
                         else {
                            var err = new Error(404);
                            throw err;
                        }
                      } else {
                        if (controllerDynamic.auth.indexOf('PortalEval') != -1) {
                            var err = new Error(402);
                            throw err;
                        } else
                        if (controllerDynamic.auth.indexOf('General') != -1) {
                            var err = new Error(401);
                            throw err;
                        } else {
                            var err = new Error(404);
                            throw err;
                        }
                      }
                    }

                    /**
                     * Check the "auth" atribute of a controller
                     */
                    // if (controllerDynamic.auth.indexOf(controllerPrototype) != -1) {

                    // }

                    /**
                     * Final validation
                     */
                    var isValid = true;
                    if (aryUrl.length > 4) {
                      isValid = false;
                    }

                    if (method == '') {
                      isValid = false;
                    }

                    if (typeof controllerDynamic[controllerPrototype] !== "function") {
                      isValid = false;
                    }

                    if (isValid) {
                        router.route(url)[method](function(ctrlReq, ctrlRes){
                            controllerDynamic[controllerPrototype](ctrlReq, ctrlRes);
                        });
                    } else {
                      res.status(404).send('Not found');
                 }
                  }

                  next();

                } catch (e) {
                  if (e.message == 401) {
                    res.status(401).redirect('/auth/login');
                  } else
                  if (e.message == 402) {
                    res.status(401).redirect('/auth' + url);
                  } else {
                    res.status(404).send('Not found 2');
                  }
                }
              });

              app.use('/', router);
            };
```

in fact that console.log(touch) get called twice if the route doesn't respond fast (in less than 8 minutes) i had no idea what is going on

Thanks guys!

Comment: You should probably regenerate your recaptcha credentials on your google account now that they've been publicly posted in your code example...

Comment: Code this long with this many levels of indentation is absolutely unreadable at 2 spaces per indent without viewing in a special code editor.  It simply does not work here.

Comment: Please see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604790/express-app-post-getting-called-multiple-times)