# Express function being called multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have this route:

```
router.get("/cat/:cat", function(req, res){
  Play.find({style: req.params.cat}).sort({date: -1}).exec(function(err, play){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      req.flash("error", "(Error - Find-2-1) Find Playlist");
      res.redirect("/index");
    } else {
      Categories.find({name: req.params.cat}).exec(function(err, cat){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("\n "+ cat +" \n");
          res.render("Categories/show.ejs", {
            ttt: cat,
            playlists: play
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });  
});
```

But when I access /cat/:cat I get "cat" printed twice. I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604790/express-app-post-getting-called-multiple-times) question, but it didnt worked. I have no idea on why it happens and it only happens with this route, the others routes works fine.

It prints when the page starts loading and then when the page finish loading.

When I get rid of the `Categories.find` process, it works fine too.

Comment: Have you tried using callback or promise instead of using exec ?

Comment: @VivekKumar How do I do this? Thank You

Comment: @VivekKumar I tried using `findById`. When I use `findById` it works fine

Comment: Do you see an error message in the console or only `cat`  being printed twice? Because it is printed twice cause of the same request then `res.render` would also be called twice, and this should emit an error. Have you ever put at `console.log('get '+req.params.cat)`  before the `Play.find` to check that you really have only one request?

Comment: @t.niese Only `cat` being printed twice. I tried using `findById`. When I use `findById` it works fine

Comment: @t.niese `console.log('get '+req.params.cat)` is also printed twice

Comment: If `console.log('get '+req.params.cat)`  right before the `Play.find({style: req.params.cat})` is printed twice, then this indicates that there are two requests done by the browser. The problem should not be related to the `find`  and and as of that using `findById` should not change anything, it at least does not make sense with the given code.

Comment: @t.niese The rest of the code is only other routes, and the code on the question is exactly the same as my code, its weird because it prints when the page starts loading and prints again when the page finish loading.

Comment: @BrunoPigatto
When you use .find it returns all documents which have matching style and you  might be having more than one of the same cat name. So basically, you should use one more other field in Find object to get the specific document.
for example : Play.find({id: '',  style: ''})